# Whats wrong in my below query

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to find out what wrong in below query but unable to do so ,

```
 connect.execute("""INSERT INTO dummy('disk_list_disk_serial_id','disk_list_disk_size','disk_list_service_vm_id','disk_list_disk_id','disk_list_storage_tier','disk_list_statfs_disk_size','storage_pool_id') VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s') """, (disk_serial_id,disk_size,service_vm_id,entity_id,storage_tier,statfs_disk_size,disk_storage_id))
```

When I am executing I am getting an error

```
ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''disk_list_disk_serial_id','disk_list_disk_size','disk_list_service_vm_id','disk' at line 1")
```

I checked after service_vm_id but could not find anything wrong.Please help me out why I am not able to run it .

Comment: No single quotes for table or column names..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not quote the field names.

Additionally, you should not the placeholder values either. The DB API does that for you when it inserts the actual values, depending on whether they are strings or not.

```
connect.execute("""INSERT INTO dummy (disk_list_disk_serial_id,disk_list_disk_size,disk_list_service_vm_id, ...) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) """, (...))
```

Answer (score 0):

Always a better way is to use a variable to create a long/complex query.
It would be better readable

```
query = """
INSERT INTO dummy(disk_list_disk_serial_id,disk_list_disk_size,disk_list_service_vm_id,disk_list_disk_id,disk_list_storage_tier,disk_list_statfs_disk_size,storage_pool_id) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s') 
""" % (disk_serial_id,disk_size,service_vm_id,entity_id,storage_tier,statfs_disk_size,disk_storage_id)
connect.execute(query)
```

ALso you don't needs quotes for `%s` if the column type is int. I hope this helps

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Umm... did you seen your query properly, you have quoted your column names using `'` with that it's no more a column name rather a string literal

your query

```
INSERT INTO dummy('disk_list_disk_serial_id', ...
```

should be

```
INSERT INTO dummy(disk_list_disk_serial_id, ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need quotes around the column names.

Edit: I didn't take a look at the tags and made a remark about the syntax that was specific to sqlite, thanks for Daniel Roseman for pointing that out. This is actually the correct way to do parameter substitution in mySQL.

Comment: This is MySQL, not sqlite.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks for pointing that out, I removed the erroneous remark from my post.